# Scrapy crawl only internal links, including relative links

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to use scrapy for crawl all internal web links of a page, such that all links on for instance www.stackovflow.com is crawled. This code sort of work:

```
   extractor = LinkExtractor(allow_domains=self.getBase(self.startDomain))

    for link in extractor.extract_links(response):
        self.registerUrl(link.url)
```

However there is a small problem, all relative paths such as `/meta` or `/questions/ask` is not crawled as the does not contain the base domain `stackoverflow.com`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: doesn't scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware  https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware do this?

Comment: Thanks I apparently found some old documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to use scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware

> Filters out Requests for URLs outside the domains covered by the
>   spider.
>
> ```
> This middleware filters out every request whose host names aren’t in the spider’s allowed_domains attribute. All subdomains of any
> ```
>
> domain in the list are also allowed. E.g. the rule www.example.org
>   will also allow bob.www.example.org but not www2.example.com nor
>   example.com.
>
> ```
> When your spider returns a request for a domain not belonging to those covered by the spider, this middleware will log a debug message
> ```
>
> similar to this one:
>
> ```
> DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.othersite.com': <GET http://www.othersite.com/some/page.html>
>
> To avoid filling the log with too much noise, it will only print one of these messages for each new domain filtered. So, for example,
> ```
>
> if another request for www.othersite.com is filtered, no log message
>   will be printed. But if a request for someothersite.com is filtered, a
>   message will be printed (but only for the first request filtered).
>
> ```
> If the spider doesn’t define an allowed_domains attribute, or the attribute is empty, the offsite middleware will allow all requests.
>
> If the request has the dont_filter attribute set, the offsite middleware will allow the request even if its domain is not listed in
> ```
>
> allowed domains.

My understanding is that the URLs are normalised before being filtered.

Comment: should OffsiteMiddleware be set to disable in settings.py ?

Comment: No 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware': 500, see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=OffsiteMiddleware